# Profile photo upload in php and database

Tags: php, html, mysql, session, file-upload

I have problem that the photo uploaded to the site but the name of it don't be saved on database .
The code upload the photo to the site but the name of the file didn't be uploaded to the database
help me, I need to know what the problem in the code?
please someone answer!

the code:

```
<?php session_start();
        $con = mysqli_connect("my host","my account","my passwod","my table name");
            $_SESSION['id'] = "$con_id";
?>

<?php

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"../userstorage/p_photos/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
                $con = mysqli_connect("my host","my account","my password","my table name");
                $q = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET image = '".$_FILES['file']['name']."' WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['id']."'");
        }
?>
```

Comment: `$id` isn't defined

Comment: where it's ?????

Comment: In your update query. When asking, 1 question mark is enough.

Comment: Is it not working

Comment: <?php session_start();
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","id8359980_accounts","poi123456","id8359980_server");
            $_SESSION['id'] = "$com_id";
?>
 
<?php
         
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"../userstorage/p_photos/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
                $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","id8359980_accounts","poi123456","id8359980_server");
                $q = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET image = '".$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']."' WHERE id = '"$_SESSION['id']"'");
        }
?>

Comment: That's unreadable. please consider [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54112416/edit) your question

Comment: I know your credentials now!

Comment: what????????????

Comment: for characters limit

Comment: Everything in your code looked correct except for that one part. If my answer helped, please upvote and accept :)

Answer (score 2):

Your error is here

```
$q = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET image = '".$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']."' WHERE id = '$id'");
```

**$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']** is the image data, while **$_FILES['file']['name']** is the name of the file. So in the end of the day you need to change this piece of code

for reference check this article on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) on how to upload and display images from a database.

Comment: I would like to know why i got downvoted for giving the obviously correct solution??

Comment: `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` is not the image data, but the temporary name of the file on the server. This is an error, but not the only one. He's using variables in the query that aren't declared/assigned. Not my downvote, but this is not *"the obviously correct solution"*

Comment: Okay I understand that, but when you are copying the file from the browser, you copy the file with **$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']** and get the represented filename with **$_FILES['file']['name']**, which is what he needed to use in the first place.

Comment: Also I can give more clearer answers with limited info from OP >.<

Comment: If you need more informations to post an answer, then don't post your answer and ask for clarification in comments.

Comment: I had more than enough info to answer this question, which i feel was the right solution